# Scala Play `@routes.Assets.versioned` causing a non descriptive error

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a problem with browser caching, so I decided to change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/accounts/dist/inline.bundle.js")"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","inline.bundle.js")"></script>
```

as we already do in other projects, but I am getting this totally unhelpful error:

```
C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2>sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
"C:\Users\xavier\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.2"\jars\sbt.jar"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 58387
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\xavier\.sbt\0.13\staging\560eb781744c869bfbb7\sbt-coveralls\project
[info] Loading project definition from C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\project
[info] Set current project to Spike2 (in build file:/C:/work/FrontServices/Spike2/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\modules\accounts\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\modules\accounts\app\com\newswhip\accounts\views\accounts.scala.html:20: too many arguments for method versioned: (file: controllers.Assets.Asset)play.api.mvc.Call
[error]     <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","inline.bundle.js")"></script>
[error]                                                                                    ^
[error] C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\modules\accounts\app\com\newswhip\accounts\views\accounts.scala.html:21: too many arguments for method versioned: (file: controllers.Assets.Asset)play.api.mvc.Call
[error]     <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","polyfills.bundle.js")"></script>
[error]                                                                                     ^
[error] C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\modules\accounts\app\com\newswhip\accounts\views\accounts.scala.html:22: too many arguments for method versioned: (file: controllers.Assets.Asset)play.api.mvc.Call
[error]     <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","styles.bundle.js")"></script>
[error]                                                                                      ^
[error] C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\modules\accounts\app\com\newswhip\accounts\views\accounts.scala.html:23: too many arguments for method versioned: (file: controllers.Assets.Asset)play.api.mvc.Call
[error]     <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","vendor.bundle.js")"></script>
[error]                                                                                       ^
[error] C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2\modules\accounts\app\com\newswhip\accounts\views\accounts.scala.html:24: too many arguments for method versioned: (file: controllers.Assets.Asset)play.api.mvc.Call
[error]     <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","main.bundle.js")"></script>
[error]                                                                                        ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (accounts/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 20-Oct-2017 10:27:09

C:\work\FrontServices\Spike2>
```

This is the code fragment from the `routes` file

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path = "/public/accounts/dist", file: Asset)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public", file)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In `src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","inline.bundle.js")"`
why are you separating the two string with comma inside versioned().

That means that you are giving `versioned()` two parameters because of which it is throwing an error because it only expects one.

Instead you should give it like this -

```
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist/inline.bundle.js")"
```

assuming inline.bundle.js is at the path `/public/accounts/dist/`

Try this out and let me know if it works. I hope it does!

Comment: I am passing 2 parameters int versioned, cause we are already doing it successfully in the other 2 projects. Besides the routes file has this line in `GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path = "/public/accounts/dist", file: Asset)` so versioned can take 2 params. I already tried merging the param into 1 string as is used with `<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/accounts/dist/main.bundle.js")"></script>` - just replaced `at` with `versioned` but I am getting "noSuchMethod + controllers.ReverseAssets.versioned" error when compiling.

Comment: The exact error is `Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: controllers.ReverseAssets.versioned(Lcontrollers/Assets$Asset;)Lplay/api/mvc/Call;`

Comment: Ok, try removing the path that you have already given in routes from inside the versioned. What I mean is, in routes you have specified the path as `/public/accounts/dist` , then remove this part when accessing this in your code. Try using - `src="@routes.Assets.versioned("inline.bundle.js")"` . I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes` definition you are doing:

```
GET     /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.versioned(path = "/public/accounts/dist", file: Asset)
```

That means the first parameter for method `Assets.versioned` is already defined (`path = "/public/accounts/dist"`). So, you have room for one more parameter only (the asset file). But in your views you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/public/accounts/dist","inline.bundle.js")"></script>
```

In other words, you are trying to define the path again, but this is the generated reverse router now (`@routes.Assets`) and not the "original" `Assets.versioned`, then you get the error.

The solution is to change the code to pass only the `file` parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("inline.bundle.js")"></script>
```